# Javascript extend object

Tags: javascript, properties

I'm looking for a review of the Javascript code which has this specifications:

> Given two objects, the function "extend" adds properties from the 2<sup>nd</sup> object to the 1<sup>st</sup> object.

Notes:

- Add any keys that are not in the 1st object.
- If the 1<sup>st</sup> object already has a given key, ignore it (do not overwrite the property value).
- Do not modify the 2<sup>nd</sup> object at all.

A runnable version can be found on [repl.it](https://repl.it/@ebrunosan/extend).

```
function extend(obj1, obj2) {
  for (var key in obj2) {
    if (!obj1.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      obj1[key] = obj2[key];
    }
  }
}
var obj1 = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2
};
var obj2 = {
  b: 4,
  c: 3
};

extend(obj1, obj2);

console.log(obj1); // --> {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}
console.log(obj2); // --> {b: 4, c: 3}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One could also use the [`in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) operator instead of [Object.hasOwnProperty()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty).

One must ask: do inherited properties count? For simple objects (like the examples `obj1` and `obj2`) it seems to not matter, but for more complex objects it will matter...

If `in` can be used, then it [may provide better performance](https://jsperf.com/in-vs-hasownproperty-for-extends).

```js
function extend(obj1, obj2) {
  for (var key in obj2) {
    if (!(key in obj1)) {
      obj1[key] = obj2[key];
    }
  }
}
var obj1 = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2
};
var obj2 = {
  b: 4,
  c: 3
};

extend(obj1, obj2);

console.log(obj1); // --> {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}
console.log(obj2); // --> {b: 4, c: 3}
```

#### P.S.

It is a shame that [Object.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) doesn't have an option to not overwrite existing properties... if it did, then the extend function could simply utilize that function...

Comment: You have to be very careful with JSpref or you end up measuring the speed of code not actually executed. Optimizer will skip code that does not create a result. Try this one (uses `soak` to ensure execution) https://jsperf.com/testin-bm67 not much between them but `hasownProperty` has a slight advantage over `in` (Chrome)

Comment: Thanks @blindman67 - I have created a separate test for this case...

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that if the first object has a property set to `undefined` and the rule states no change then your code is almost spot on.

Some minor changes

- The variable `key` into a `const`.
- Return the extended object.
- Vet the arguments.

Thus

```
function extend(obj1, obj2) {
    if (obj1 !== null && typeof obj1 === "object") {
        if (obj2 !== null && typeof obj2 === "object") {
            for (const key in obj2) { 
                if (!obj1.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                    obj1[key] = obj2[key];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return obj1;
}
extend({a: 1, b: undefined}, {b: 1, c: 2}); // returns {a: 1, b: undefined, c: 2}
```